# npm - How to fix error code ELIFECYCLE after updating @angular/cli

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have this error after updating @angular/cli both global and local to the latest version. I've tried cleaning cache, deleting node modules folder and reinstalling but the error still persists. Hope someone knows how to fix this.

Here is the full console log when I ran npm after updating:

> PS D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project> npm start
>
> name-card-angular@0.0.0 start D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project
>   ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxyconfig.json
>
> trustedSubscriber._addParentTeardownLogic is not a function
>   TypeError: trustedSubscriber._addParentTeardownLogic is not a function
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber [as constructor] (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:45:43)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.OuterSubscriber [as constructor] (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\OuterSubscriber.js:20:42)
>       at new MergeMapSubscriber (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:48:28)
>       at MergeMapOperator.call (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:39:33)
>       at Observable.subscribe (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
>       at D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToObservable.js:10:20
>       at Object.subscribeToResult (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber._next (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:55:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\map.js:52:26)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at TapSubscriber._next (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:62:26)
>       at TapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:64:18)
>       at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (D:\KIS\Name-Card-Frontend-Project\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:84:26)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! name-card-angular@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxyconfig.json`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the name-card-angular@0.0.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-21T17_34_25_541Z-debug.log

**UPDATE**
The error disappeared after commenting the `_addParentTeardownLogic` function from the file at the link above. There're some times the code works fine when commenting error function of the modules. Really don't know why they added these functions just to be commented?